# chartjs bar chart align the legend to left position

Tags: chart.js, legend, legend-properties

I'm working chartjs bar chart, i need to align the legend to left side, i tried position: "left" but it moves chart to the right

is there any other way to position the legend to left ?

```
legend: {
       position: "left"
         },
```

Comment: Did you try like this? `legend: { position: 'left' }`

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem i tried but it results the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
legend: {
  display: true,
  position: 'left',
}
```